# How can I shorten the command for making a Git commit with author specified, without setting global configuration?

Tags: git

I am working on some scripts on a shared server, and I need to commit my progress to a Git repository periodically. Since the server and the user I am logged in as are both shared, I don't want to set the global user names and e-mails, which is the common solution to not entering the commit author every time. If I don't specify any author, Git will assume the name name based on the shared system's user and host names, but then the commits won't be associated with me. I have been making my commits with the following command to address this:

> git commit -m "Commit message" --author="FirstName LastName "

How can I shorten this command so I don't have to type out the author every time, but without setting global configuration options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are at least two options to address this:

**Set Repository-Specific Options**

Have each user that uses the machine make their own clone of the repository. Then, each user can set a local user name and e-mail configuration option in their copy of the repository:

> git config user.name "FirstName LastName"
>   git config user.email "email@domain.com"

Simply leaving off the `--global` option will create a **[user]** section in the repository's *.git/config* file, so when the user makes a commit in the repository, that user name and e-mail will be attached to the commit.

**Create an Alias for the Command**

You can set an alias for committing that includes the author:

> git config --global alias.commitauthorname 'commit --author="FirstName LastName " -m'

Then commit using that command:

> git commitauthorname "Commit message"

You can leave the `-m` out of the alias if you don't want to use that option every time.

Note: This approach will cause Git to generate the following message with each commit that it is used with:

> Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.

Also, each commit that is made with the alias will have the *author* set accurately, but the *committer* metadata attached to the commit will still be based on the username and hostname that Git found.